# How to download attachment from XOP/MTOM response

Tags: c#, wcf, mtom, xop

We use a third party service which returns attachments as web service response in the xop format as below

```
<result>
        <document-id>232</document-id>
        <application-id>34343</application-id>
        <document-type>CUSTOMER_UPLOADED</document-type>
        <owner-id>434</owner-id>
        <owner-type>CONSUMER</owner-type>
        <file-name>abc.jpeg</file-name>
        <content>
           <xop:Include href="cid:d4fc646b-9172-43b1-afdc-dfd70ea13e66-1@cxf.apache.org"                   xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/>
        </content>

 </result>
```

Once we get the response We need to convert the file into binary and send to other party .
How do I download the file from this response above using C#.net . Any pointers please ?

Comment: Did you ever get this solved?